# Query to apply rate from the interval of dates

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have two tables in my oracle database

Table A : stDate, endDate, salary

For example:

```
03/02/2010 28/02/2010 2000
05/03/2012 29/03/2012 2500
```

Table B : DateOfActivation, rate

For example:

```
01/01/2010 1.023
01/11/2011 1.063
01/01/2012 1.075
```

I would like to have a SQL query displaying the sum of salary of table A with each salary multiplied by the rate of table B depending on the activation date.

Here, for the first salary the good rate is the first one (1.023) because the second rate has a date of activation that is later than stDate and endDate interval.
For the second salary, the third rate is applied because activation date of the rate was before the interval of dates of the second salary.

so the sum is this one : 2000 * 1.023 + 2500 * 1.075 = 4733.5

I hope I am clear

Thanks

Comment: How does the salary should be calculated in a case when the activation date is between start-date and end-date ? For example: `startDate =03/02/2010 endDate=28/02/2010  salary=2000, dateOfActivation=22/02/2010 1.023` ?

Comment: Is there an issue with the data in your tables? Right now, there is no `DateOfActivation` the falls inside either periods from `table A`. Also, I don't understand why the 2nd row isn't accounted for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rate must be active before the beginning of the interval (i.e. DateOfActivation < stDate), you could do something like this ([see fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d85b/1)):

`SELECT SUM(salary*
        (SELECT rate from TableB WHERE DateOfActivation=
          (SELECT MAX(DateOfActivation) FROM TableB WHERE DateOfActivation < stDate)
        )) FROM TableA;`

Answer (score 0):

This problem becomes much easier if DateofActivation is a true effective dated table with rate_start_date and rate_end_date such that a new row cannot be created where its start date  or end_date will lie within an existing rate_start_date -- rate_end_date pair. The currently active row typically would have a NULL value for rate_end_date. In addition, Likely, you would want an EMP_ID on the salary table to be able to sum the rows to finish the calculation; and one needs to consider the following cases:

```
 Start Date is between rate_start and rate_end
 End Date is  between rate_start and rate_end
 Rate_start and Rate_end are between start_date and end_date (sandwiched)
```

If you run the following snippet you will see we can artificially create our rate_end_dates as follows:

```
       SELECT D.ACTIVEDATE, D.RATE, NVL(MIN(E.ACTIVEDATE)-1,SYSDATE) ENDDATE
       FROM XX_DATEOFACTIVATION D, XX_DATEOFACTIVATION E
       WHERE D.ACTIVEDATE<E.ACTIVEDATE(+)
       GROUP BY D.ACTIVEDATE, D.RATE
       ORDER BY D.ACTIVEDATE
```

Proposed code is as follows:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
     (SELECT S.*, T.RATE, S.SALARY*T.RATE
     FROM  XX_SAL_HIST S, 
    (SELECT D.ACTIVEDATE, D.RATE, NVL(MIN(E.ACTIVEDATE)-1,SYSDATE) ENDDATE
      FROM XX_DATEOFACTIVATION D, XX_DATEOFACTIVATION E
      WHERE D.ACTIVEDATE<E.ACTIVEDATE(+) 
      GROUP BY D.ACTIVEDATE, D.RATE) T  -- creating synthetic rate_end_date
     WHERE S.STDATE BETWEEN T.ACTIVEDATE AND T.ENDDATE)
     UNION
    (SELECT S.*, T.RATE, S.SALARY*T.RATE
     FROM  XX_SAL_HIST S, 
     (SELECT D.ACTIVEDATE, D.RATE, NVL(MIN(E.ACTIVEDATE)-1,SYSDATE) ENDDATE
       FROM XX_DATEOFACTIVATION D, XX_DATEOFACTIVATION E
       WHERE D.ACTIVEDATE<E.ACTIVEDATE(+)
       GROUP BY D.ACTIVEDATE, D.RATE) T  -- creating synthetic rate_end_date
     WHERE S.ENDDATE BETWEEN T.ACTIVEDATE AND T.ENDDATE)
    UNION
     (SELECT S.*, T.RATE, S.SALARY*T.RATE
     FROM  XX_SAL_HIST S, 
     (SELECT D.ACTIVEDATE, D.RATE, NVL(MIN(E.ACTIVEDATE)-1,SYSDATE) ENDDATE
       FROM XX_DATEOFACTIVATION D, XX_DATEOFACTIVATION E
       WHERE D.ACTIVEDATE<E.ACTIVEDATE(+)
       GROUP BY D.ACTIVEDATE, D.RATE) T  -- creating synthetic rate_end_date
     WHERE T.ACTIVEDATE BETWEEN S.STDATE AND S.ENDDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to transform `Table B` (`Table2` in the query) to have, for each row, the start and end date

```
Select DateOfActivation AS startDate
     , rate
     , NVL(LEAD(DateOfActivation, 1) OVER (ORDER BY DateOfActivation)
         , TO_DATE('9999/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')) AS endDate
From   Table2
```

Now we can join this table with `Table A` (`Table1` in the query)

```
WITH Rates AS (
  Select DateOfActivation AS startDate
       , rate
       , NVL(LEAD(DateOfActivation, 1) OVER (ORDER BY DateOfActivation)
           , TO_DATE('9999/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')) AS endDate
  From   Table2)
Select SUM(s.salary * r.rate)
From   Rates r
       INNER JOIN Table1 s ON s.stDate < r.endDate AND s.endDate > r.startDate
```

The `JOIN` condition get every row in `Table A` that are at least partially in the activation period of the rate, if you need it to be inclusive you can alter it as in the following query

```
WITH Rates AS (
  Select DateOfActivation AS startDate
       , rate
       , NVL(LEAD(DateOfActivation, 1) OVER (ORDER BY DateOfActivation)
           , TO_DATE('9999/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')) AS endDate
  From   Table2)
Select SUM(s.salary * r.rate)
From   Rates r
       INNER JOIN Table1 s ON s.stDate >= r.startDate AND s.endDate <= r.endDate
```

Comment: Nice demo of the "LEAD" function.  I would still prefer  SYSDATE as a default versus 12/31/9999. minor point though.  Sweet code.

Comment: Also -- i would prefer to set end_dates like:
Select activedate AS startDate
     , rate
     , NVL(LEAD(activedate -1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY activedate)
         , TO_DATE('9999/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')) AS endDate
From   xx_dateofactivation

Comment: @CharlieK I'm not sure that every date is in the past, even if it's quite probable, for the end of activation you can be right but it depends on the boundary condition, it can also be taken care of changing the `WHERE` condition to strictly less than (`s.endDate < r.endDate`)